# ASP.NET MVC & EF 6 - convert to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In existing ASP.NET MVC & EF 6 project I want to replace below CRUD 
actions in controller to Stored procedures:

> public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,WebHookName,
>   EnableCDR")] Table_WebHook table_WebHook )
>
> public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,WebHookName,EnableCDR")]
>   Table_WebHook table_WebHook)

Thanks

Comment: You do not convert Actions to Stored procedures. You convert the logic of persisting. If the persisting logic was in your code base you convert that into SP. And your code calls that SP.

Comment: So I want to keep UI as is, but only move code into SP. how I can do that? Can you please post example or detailed instructions?

Comment: You should be able to find a lot of examples please google it. Some i could find are [1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-mvc/) [2](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)